# Automatic dependency generation and compilation in non-flat directory src

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu, rule, recipe

I'd like to adapt the [combined automatic dependency approach](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) to a non-flat directory situation where headers are located under ./include/ and implementation files under ./src/ (while Makefile is in the current directory .). I'd like to hold all intermediate and .d (dependency) files inside a separate directory (potentially separate ./build/ and ./.deps/) . To avoid potential clash for dependency files when more than one file with the same name in different subdirectories of ./include/ and ./src/ can exist, I guess building the same structure as in ./src/ in ./.deps could be a solution.

Apart from adding -I directive to the compile phase in the above linked Makefile, what else should I add?

Comment: IMO this isn't an appropriate question for SO.  You should try to make it work and if you have a problem you can't figure out, then you can ask for help about that problem, with a detailed description and a specific question that people can answer.

Comment: I'd suggest you to have a look at non-recursive libraries, like https://github.com/igagis/prorab/blob/master/wiki/TutorialBasicConcepts.md it has all these problems solved already, you can just use it. Or you can look how the problem is solved there and do your own implementation

Comment: @MadScientist Yeah, I'm going to ask a few more specific questions.

Comment: @igagis I'll have a look but it looks overcomplicated.

Comment: @greendiod well, this is what it becomes when you want to resolve all the problems. You don't even have to implement your own solution, you can just use this one, without caring about how complex it is inside... You will only save time and avoid bugs.