# Isomorphic build directory structure with Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, directory, gnu

The combined [automatic dependency approach with a non-flat src directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045406/automatic-dependency-generation-and-compilation-in-non-flat-directory-) is too broad a question so I'm going to break it up with a first question.

How to best generate a build directory structure **isomorphic** with the src directory structure (see **Q1** below)?

My Makefile at the time being (no dependency handling at all for now, that would be the next question on how to add combined/or even standalone separate  dependency -- with isomorphic directory structure as well -- step/target):

## First part (copy/paste in edit mode starting here to try it out)

### Various dirs (src directory structure possibily nested)

```
base = .
incdir = $(base)/include
srcdir = $(base)/src
builddir = $(base)/build/debug # To open the possibility for a release build

includes = -I$(incdir)
```

### Binary target

```
binary = my_bin
```

### Flags for my compiler

```
STD = -std=c++14
WARN = -Wall -Wextra
CXXFLAGS = -g $(strip $(includes)) # Most variables stripped before calling the compiler for better readability, but not strictly needed.
ALL_CXXFLAGS = $(STD) $(WARN) $(CXXFLAGS)

COMPILE.cpp = $(CXX) $(strip $(ALL_CXXFLAGS)) $(strip $(CPPFLAGS)) -c
```

## Where I try to actually build an isomorphic directory structure

### My source files

```
ext = cpp
src = $(wildcard $(srcdir)/*.$(ext))
```

### Q1. I do it as follows but is it the most robust and efficient way?

```
obj = $(subst $(srcdir),$(builddir),$(src:.$(ext)=.o))

.PHONY: all clean distclean
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .$(ext) .o


all: $(ALL)

$(TARGET): $(obj)
    $(CXX) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

$(obj): | $(builddir)
```

### Q2. Is it how I should actually create the build directory structure?

```
$(builddir):
    mkdir -p $@

$(builddir)/%.o: $(srcdir)/%.$(ext) $(incdir)/%.h
    $(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

$(builddir)/%.o: $(srcdir)/%.$(ext)
    $(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

## End copy-pasting

I currently need explicit targets/prerequisites with the builddir, srcdir, and incdir variables. Before I go the automatic dependency generator way,

### Q3. How could I just use plain %.o: %.c rule if possible?

**Current problem:** Actually, the previous Makefile works if header files are all stuffed under include and source files are all stuffed under src (notwithstanding the dependency generation part). However, if I have, say, a util/ subdirectory in both include/ src/ (headers in include/util would be referenced as #include "util/tool1.h" etc. elsewhere for now) this Makefile would miserably fail.